# Tkinter: How to grid inside of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am trying to add a variable inside of class, and also grid it with the `e1.grid()` command. I can create the variable inside of the class but for some reason I can't `grid` the variable and I can't `grid` text either. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
from tkinter import Entry

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, 
        weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", 
font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: 
controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", 
font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: 
controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is preventing you from "gridding" them?

Comment: this error:  
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame.!pageone which already has slaves managed by pack

Comment: That error is telling you precisely what's wrong: you can't use both `grid` and `pack` on widgets that have a common parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use pack with grid together.

'''

```
e1 = Entry(self).pack()
#e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

'''

so...

```
import tkinter as tk                
from tkinter import font  as tkfont 
from tkinter import Entry

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, 
        weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()

        e1 = Entry(self).pack()
        #e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

**update**

if you want use grid method you must grid for all widgets in the relative page

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        e1 = Entry(self)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: how am I supposed to grid the entry here?